# compact() variables into array by prefix?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

Is this possible?

Like make an array with all the variables that have a certain prefix?

I don't need the keys just the values, but I guess I could use array_values on the array.

Comment: You will have to analyze the symbol table somehow (not sure how personally, but I'm sure it can be done) to get these variables and handle them as you will -- if you *need* to do this you may want to rethink how you are doing things.

Comment: well if it's not possible i'll just type each of the 15 variables manually into compact() :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to do this, it's probably not written very well to begin with, but, here's how to do it :)

```
$foobar = 'test';
$anothervar = 'anothertest';
$foooverflow = 'fo';
$barfoo = 'foobar';

$prefix = 'foo';
$output = array();
$vars = get_defined_vars();
foreach ($vars as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) $output[] = $value;
}

/*
$output = array(
    'test', // from $foobar
    'fo', // from $foooverflow
);
*/
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php

Answer (score 2):

my eyes are bleeding a little, but I couldn't resist a one liner.

```
print_r(iterator_to_array(new RegexIterator(new ArrayIterator(get_defined_vars()), '/^' . preg_quote($prefix) . '/', RegexIterator::GET_MATCH, RegexIterator::USE_KEY)));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about variables in the global scope, you could do this with `$GLOBALS[]`:

```
$newarray = array();

// Iterate over all current global vars 
foreach ($GLOBALS as $key => $value) {
  // And add those with keys matching prefix_ to a new array
  if (strpos($key, 'prefix_' === 0) {
    $newarray[$key] = $value;
  }
}
```

If you have lots and lots of variables in global scope, this is going to be slower in execution than manually adding them all to `compact()`, but faster to type out.

#### Addendum

I would just add (though I suspect you already know) that if you have the ability to refactor this code, you are better off to group the related variables together into an array in the first place.

Comment: wouldn't iterating trough get_defined_vars() be a better idea? anyway I was looking for something lighter, built-in php etc.

Comment: yes, but I'm doing some stuff with the variables first and I don't like to use the array for that, because the code looks ugly. For example `$arr['some_var'] = substr($arr['some_var'], 0, 15);` it looks nicer with `$some_var`

Answer (score 1):

This, my second answer, shows how to do this without making a mess of the global scope by using a simple PHP object:

```
$v = new stdClass();
$v->foo = "bar";
$v->scope = "your friend";
$v->using_classes = "a good idea";
$v->foo_overflow = "a bad day";

echo "Man, this is $v->using_classes!\n";

$prefix = "foo";
$output = array();
$refl = new ReflectionObject($v);
foreach ($refl->getProperties() as $prop) {
        if (strpos($prop->getName(), $prefix) === 0) $output[] = $prop->getValue($v);
}

var_export($output);
```

Here's the output:

```
Man, this is a good idea!
array (
  0 => 'bar',
  1 => 'a bad day',
)
```